# Error while trying to use linkedin authorization with OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I'm trying to authorize my iPhone app using the linkedin api but I keep getting errors in the authorization phase.
I copied the URL from the app and tried to see how it act on my browser (chrome) and I get an error over there too.
The URL is:
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code%20&client_id=/myClientId/%20&scope=r_fullprofile%20r_emailaddress%20&state=/stateString/&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Egoogle%2Ecom

in my browser I get to the main page of linked in with the following error in a red bar on top:
There was an unexpected problem that prevented us from completing your request.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have some extra spaces(see bold) in your url string:

Your string: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code**%20**&client_id=/myClientId/**%20**&scope=r_fullprofile%20r_emailaddress%20&state=/stateString/&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Egoogle%2Ecom

Try using: 
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=/myClientId/&scope=r_fullprofile%20r_emailaddress**%20**&state=/stateString/&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Egoogle%2Ecom

Comment: I still get the same problem even when I remove the extra spaces :/

Comment: I found another extra space (before state). Can you post the un-encoded url ? Also check that your clientid is correct.

Comment: I rechecked the client id and I looked for all the extra spaces, I still get the same error when I try to use this url in my browser.

Comment: Hm. Well, your url seems correct. Can't help without more information though.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help so far, what information do you need?

Answer (score 0):

This error may be due to `scope=r_fullprofile`. LinkedIn does not give full access to app by default. [Reference](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition).

I am using helloJs in [here](http://onlineinvite.in) and I have used `r_basicprofile`, this works for me.